# Text to speech tests

Tags: android

I Have an Android application for testing that uses Speech recognition. I want to create tests using text to speech API (provided by android or any other) such that the test case will convert the text sentences provided into speech and my Application responds accordingly. Is this possible???

Comment: have you tried any thing.??

Comment: yes i have tried to write junit test case and use the tts API provided by android but i am not able to initialize the tts object as the object requires to implement on click listener and extend class activity but for junit test case i am extending the ActivityInstrumentation2 class.So just wanted to know whether it is feasible.